# realm android - how to update specific tables or values on migration without changing the rest

Tags: android, database, realm, database-migration

I have changed realm database file in assets and I'd like to make some changes in the current db but all the rest should remain the same so I can't deleteOnMigrationNeeded. I need to update only one table and only specific values in another. How can I access the new realm in Migration.class to retrieve new values from there? Or how I can solve my problem generally?

This is the way config looks:

```
RealmConfiguration config = new RealmConfiguration.Builder()
            .name("data.realm")
            .schemaVersion(1)
            .migration(new Migration())
            .assetFile("data.realm")
            .build();
```

"migrate" method in Migration.class is now empty

Comment: See `RealmObjectSchema.transform()` https://realm.io/docs/java/4.3.1/api/io/realm/RealmObjectSchema.html#transform-io.realm.RealmObjectSchema.Function-

Comment: @beeender but how can I retrieve data from the new db file from assets, without hardcoding?

Answer (score 0):

If only a few values are to be updated instead of migrating the entire database you should search and update that particular value during an initial stage of app launch as in during splash screen.